# Unique constraint violation blows MySQL replication

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, replication

I have an interesting issue with MySQL replication. The environment consists of two MySQL nodes, replicated Master-Master through standard Mysql mechanisms, and simple database with following structure:

```
CREATE DATABASE `replication_test` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci */;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(65) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `value_UNIQUE` (`value`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

now it all works flawlessly, until I hit somehow common situation, that is unique constraint violation. Simple code, like one below

```
try {
    $stmtL = $this->connectionL->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)');
    $stmtL->bindParam(':name', "name", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmtL->bindParam(':value', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    echo $stmtL->execute(), "<br/>";
    //usleep($delay);
    $stmtL = $this->connectionL->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)');
    $stmtL->bindParam(':name', "name", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmtL->bindParam(':value', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    echo $stmtL->execute(), "<br/>";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage(), "<br>";
}
```

works as expected, that is throws PDO exception, but at the same time blows the replication with `Slave SQL: Error 'Duplicate entry`.
Now I do not believe that such simple thing could stop replication. Anyone faced similar issue, and care to share the solution?